# Indentation not working for some paragraphs

Tags: indentation

Some paragraphs in my document do not indent, what ever I try. I have solved some of them using the \parindent and \usepackage{indentfirst} but these specific ones do not seem to work. In those specific paragraphs, I include some math environments. Following each paragraph is a math environment on its own line. 
Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Here is the code and subsequent pdf view:
[image]

The added code at the beginning of the document:

[image]

Comment: Depending on your `\documentclass`, the indentation may be set to zero by default.  Add, for example, `\parindent=15pt\relax` to your preamble and see what happens upon recompilation.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Just posting code from the middle of the document is not sufficient, we need to see what documentclass etc. is being used.  Please provide a short [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't use `$$ ... $$` in LaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). For single line equations, use `\[ ... \]`, for multiline equations without alignment (like your first two equation blocks, add `\usepackage{amsmath}` if you haven't already, and use `\begin{gather*} first line \\ second line \\ third line \end{gather*}`.

Comment: never use a blank line before display math (and don't use `$$` for display math in latex) you appear to have parindent set to 0pt. but as you have shown no code it is hard to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately @StevenBSegletes, the \parindent=15pt\relax did not change a thing. I had set \setlength{\parindent}{6ex}

Comment: It is better to post code itself, rather than images of code.  That way, those who would otherwise help you can copy/paste the code.  With an image, that is not possible.